Are these two circuits equivalent? How to prove it?
I have two circuits as shown below. Circuit (a) contains two switches  S1  and  S2 , while circuit (b) is a fixed parallel network of resistors. When both switches are closed，I want to know if these two circuits are equivalent.
My Questions:

Are these two circuits equivalent?

If they are equivalent, how can this be formally proven?

If they are not equivalent, can you provide an explanation of why and how they differ?


I am struggling to understand the relationship between these two circuits. Any detailed explanation or step-by-step analysis would be very helpful.


The nodes and connections in the schematic are totally the circuit definition and formal proof. I mean, you could take a crayon or marker pen and highlight where all the connections are joined and see that for yourself or, you could draw both circuits in a simulator and see that they have the same node voltages at every node.

Looks like a Hamon divider topology.

See also this question on the Physics Stack Exchange.

With both switches closed, the two circuits are equivalent, it is sufficient to arrange the components differently but without changing the network topology, as in the following image:


Thank you very much, your diagram is very clear and perfectly solves my problem.


Are these two circuits equivalent?

There are two nodes that are labeled. They are labeled (a) and (b). There is a third node in the right hand circuit. Label it (c). When the switches are closed in the left hand circuit, there is also a third node. Label it (c).

Now, each resistor is connected to two nodes. Are they the same two nodes in each circuit? Or do they connect to different nodes?
If all the resistors connect to equivalent nodes in each circuit, and each resistor has the same value in each circuit, then the circuits must be equivalent.

Thank you for your response.
Indeed, these two circuits are equivalent, as stated in my textbook.
However, I still don’t understand why they are equivalent. I’m also a bit confused about what you mean by “c” in your explanation. Could you please mark it or draw a diagram to clarify?
Thank you very much!

The left hand circuit actually has five nodes. Closing the switches collapses it into three nodes which are then identical to the right hand circuit.

@Finbarr. Yes. "When the switches are closed in the left hand circuit, there is also a third node."

@MathKeepsMeBusy Node (c) is always there, whether the switches are closed or not.

@Finbarr, yes, but as you observe, there are not three nodes when the switches are open, but more. I didn't make any claim about the circuit when the switches are open, only about the circuit when the switches are closed, because that was a premiss of the question.

Thanks for your answer, I understand the circuit now

I have noticed some confusion in the other discussions, so I decided to draw the second circuit, with the switches added at equivalent points. As a bonus, I drew a table with all 4 states of S1 and S2 and the corresponding resistances. I hope this will help with visualisation.

